# How to filter a table based on yesterday date in MS Access VBA Code?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been trying to do a simple Access to excel export using `TransferSpreadsheet`.

```
Public Function Test()
   Dim table_to_export As String
    Dim excel_file_name As String
    Dim has_header As Boolean

    'Name of the Access table to export:
    table_to_export = "AttendanceLogs"

    'Path of the file to put data in.  Update with your own path:
    excel_file_name = "F:\Test\Att.xlsx"

    'Export headers with data:
    has_header = True

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, table_to_export, excel_file_name
End Function
```

Export is working fine, 
Table has a column `AttendanceDate`.

Is there any way I could add filter to the table based on a date column(filter only yesterday's records) and then export to excel

Comment: Have a look on this article. [Article Link](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/how-export-between-two-date-range-data-to-excel-through-cmdbutton.294960/)

Comment: @Harun24HR, sure will give a try now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Try this .. If your table contains column "Date", then you can filter it as ... `table_to_export.Filter = "Date = Date - 1".... 
 table_to_export.FilterOn = True`

Comment: Naresh Bhople, Thank you for your comment, I gave a try too. Giving an error - Invalid Qualifier

Comment: Also there is no form involved, just to let you know @NareshBhople

Comment: It is a function

Comment: Oh.. Yes, filterOn works on forms.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqagQvFe-mA .... Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query:

```sql
Select * From AttendanceLogs Where AttendanceDate = DateAdd("d", -1, Date())
```

Save it as, say, *AttendanceLogsYesterday*.

Then adjust your code:

```vb
Dim query_to_export As String

' Name of the Access query to export:
query_to_export = "AttendanceLogsYesterday"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, query_to_export, excel_file_name
```

Comment: Gustav, Thank you for your detailed answer.. Helped a lot.